# Convert muliple columns and rows to just one

Tags: vba

I'm trying to convert a table of data (no headers/rows data) to a single column by using VBA.

Sample as below:

```
123    580    255    
15     58     255
154
```

final outcome should read:

```
123
15
154
580
58
255
255
```

(note: no blanks)

I tried all day using for-next and do-while loops and so on, without any good results.

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly didn't work out well while trying your various attempts to solve it? Its hard to find out, what you need.

Comment: pimpf0r, table consists of various data, range a1:c10. it as contains blanks. What I want the same data "transposed" in a single column without blanks.

Comment: I got that already. Your question is quite clear about what you want, but you haven't said yet, what your actual problem is. "any good results" is vague. Are you expecting someone doing the work for you according to your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this do the trick for you?

```
Dim c As Range
Dim iRow As Integer, iColumn As Integer

'Find first empty cell in column A
Set c = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
Do Until c.Value = ""
    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

iRow = 1
iColumn = 2

Do Until Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iColumn).Value = ""

    iRow = 1

    Do Until Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iColumn).Value = ""

        c.Value = Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iColumn).Value
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
        iRow = iRow + 1

    Loop

    iColumn = iColumn + 1

Loop
```

If you have some empty cells within the Columns B+, then maybe you could think about adding a range.sort right after opening the first loop.